# R CMD check with specified library path

Tags: r

I am working on a package which I can load using devtools. But

```
R CMD check asm
```

gives me an error message

```
Error : package ‘seedDisp’ required by ‘asm’ could not be found
```

Which is kind of obvious as it is not installed in the global library.

But: I have installed installed in a local library (`./library`) and I have a `.Rprofile` file in the directory from which I run the checks as follow:

```
.libPaths(normalizePath("library"))
```

So when I run R and use `devtools` and `load_all(.)` it loads as the package `seedDisp` is installed.

It seems that `R CMD check` does ignore the library location which is set via the `.Rprofile` file.

So I tried

```
 R CMD CHECK -l ./library asm_0.0.1.tar.gz
```

but it seems that -l only is used to install ***in*** and not to look for installed packages.

How can I tell `R CMD check` to look for installed packages in the library at `./library` ?

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this is via the R_LIBS_USER variable so I generally do

```
R_LIBS_USER=/some/other/path R CMD check asm_0.0.1.tar.gz
```

If that variable is generally set on your system, you need to do the usual trick of appending, or just set it in your shell via e.g.

```
export R_LIBS_USER="/some/other/path:${R_LIBS_USER}"
R CMD check asm_0.0.1.tar.gz
```

This mechanism is independent of how you call `R CMD check` it will work with or with devtools.

Comment: @Rainer Why not set the R_LIBS_USER variable in your .profile? Then you won't need to worry about doing anything special in a makefile

Comment: Because I use this as a project specific setting. For different projects, I have different ```./library```  directories, and sometimes not. So sometimes, when there is a ```./library``` directory, I want to use it ***instead*** of my normal user library, if it is not, I ***only*** want to use the standard user library.

Comment: Then _you_ need a project-specific setup. Maybe a `.Rprofile` in that directory.  Maybe a shell-script to launch this.  Maybe something else.  Your setup. Your solution :)

Comment: By the way Docker is very good for this type of separation too; but in the simplest case it really just a shell script wrapper that you need here.  Even works on Windoze as a bat file.

Comment: That is the problem - I have a .Rprofile file with the in the questions showed content in the project folder which works if I run R interactive, but seems to be ignored when using R CMD.

Comment: So wrap R CMD ... inside a shell script that sets the env. var.

Comment: I think that would de the easiest. But I still don't understand why R CMD does not read the .Rprofile in the directory where it is executed.

Comment: OK - I am using ```bash -c "export R_LIBS_USER=./library; $(R) CMD check --library=./library $(TARBALL)"``` in the Makefile and this works. Thanks a lot.